# Why the JOIN doesn't use index?

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have a query like this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT dictionary.id, dictionary.word, lwd.grammatical_role, lwd.phonetics
FROM loghatnameh_dehkhoda dictionary
LEFT JOIN loghatnameh_words_details lwd ON lwd.word = dictionary.word 
WHERE dictionary.word= "سلام" and dictionary.id= 321780 LIMIT 1
```

Also, here is the result of `EXPLAIN`:

[image]

As you can see, that `join` is not optimized. Since a full scan happened and 80147 rows scanned. It should be noted, I have an **index** on both columns on the `join`. I mean `loghatnameh_dehkhoda(word)` and `loghatnameh_words_details(word)` columns. But still no index get used (apparently)

Noted that those two tables/columns are: (not sure if it's related to the topic)

```
- `loghatnameh_dehkhoda     => MyISAM / utf8mb4_unicode_ci
- loghatnameh_words_details => InnoDB / utf8_bin
```

Any idea how can I make it more optimal?

Comment: Post **all** of the `CREATE INDEX` statements on your `loghatnameh_words_details` and `loghatnameh_dehkhoda` tables.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`?

Answer (score 1):

When `JOINing` on a `VARCHAR`, the `INDEX` will not be used unless both the `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` are the same between the tables.  (The `ENGINE` is not critical.  But, I would recommend moving all your tables to InnoDB for other reasons.)

These indexes may be useful:

```
dictionary:  INDEX(word, id)
lwd:  INDEX(word,  grammatical_role, phonetics)
```

Is there some reason for having two separate tables?  The column names sound like things that might be in a single table with `PRIMARY KEY(word)`.

I am puzzled by the `WHERE` clause testing both `word` and `id`.  Please explain.

Is the `LIMIT 1` necessary?  If there can be more than one row, which one do you want?  (Perhaps you need an `ORDER BY`?)